# Get element by half classname (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to to get in titels a list of the 3 links by calling them through the function
everything goes well untill it comes to the last part of the (javascript) code. When it execute that code it says 'undefined' 3 times..

Why does it not just show the 3 names?

HTML

```
<h3>
<a id="126" class="6.3 linksh3 filmnaam" href="#">Name1</a></h3>
<h3>
<a id="100" class="7.4 linksh3 filmnaam" href="#">Name2</a></h3>
<h3>
<a id="101" class="6.4 linksh3 filmnaam" href="#">Name3</a></h3>
```

Javascript

```
    for (v = 0; v < classname.length; v++) { //classname = ["6.3", "6.4", "7.4"]
        titels.push(document.getElementsByClassName(classname[v]).innerHTML);
        console.log(titels[v]);
    }
```

(no jQuery)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Those are not valid classnames.  Classnames can only start with an underscore or a letter (or technically a hyphen if followed by a letter or underscore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements, not a single element, so you are trying to call `.innerHTML` on an array object, not a HTMLElement.

```
titels.push(document.getElementsByClassName(classname[v])[0].innerHTML);
```

Will access the `.innerHTML` of the first element of that array.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ndpx6g7/

Answer (score 0):

This returns a HTMLCollection of matching elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(classname[v])
```

try this instead:

```
for (v = 0; v < classname.length; v++) { //classname = ["6.3", "6.4", "7.4"]
    titels.push(document.getElementsByClassName(classname[v])[0].innerHTML);
    console.log(titels[v]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

getElementByClassName() return an array, you need to add [0] after your  getElementByClassName() Like this

getElementByClassName()[0].innerHTML